# Internationalization of Rails CRUD links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

I find myself adding seemingly identical translations over and over again, whenever I create a new model and add CRUD functionality.

Does Rails have any in-bult feature to automatically generate link texts, like:

```
link_to t('.create_new_post'), new_post_path
```

but with an API along

```
link_to new_post_path
```

which then infers some translation of "create" and interpolates it with the human name of the model from I18n to produce something like

```
<a href="/posts/new">Create Post</a>
```

The same question goes for updates and deletions along with flash messages for those.

Answer (score 1):

Not for `link_to`, no. But for Form Helpers, yes, there is.

For example, you can write:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  f.text_field :name
  f.submit
```

Notice that no additional arguments are passed to `f.submit`. This will result in something like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create User">
```

Form helpers are automatically translated. You can reference them under:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      user:
        create: "Sign Up"
        update: "Save"
```